# Calling a PowerShell script from VBA in a synced location (SharePoint)

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a working VBA script that calls a Powershell script as follows:

```
Call Shell("powershell -executionpolicy bypass & """ & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FTP\FTP.ps1""")
```

The workbook path is H:\ABC\TSV\Forecast\Worksheets

If I move the workbook and the script to C:\Test it executes the script.

However, if I move the workbook and script to a synced location (SharePoint), it doesn't execute the script. Is the synced location's file path is too long? The file path is 72 characters (e.g. C:\Users\MyUsername\SharePointSite\SharePoint-Library\Forecast\Worksheets).

How do I get around this?

Comment: If you run `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` in the SharePoint location do you get the path you expect?

Comment: Yes, exactly C:\Users\MyUsername\SharePointSite\SharePoint-Library\Forecast\Worksheets

Comment: Do you have the right credentials to run files from that location? Theoretically, it shouldn't be a problem. Can you save your modifications in the workbook keeping the code when it is in that location?

Comment: I do, I set my execution policy to remote signed already. Yes, I can save to that location just fine and I can run the script from that location within Powershell just fine too. I wonder if I could run a batch script from that location...

Comment: So calling a batch script that calls the ps script is not working either unless I run the batch from the command line. The batch script's current directory is 'C:\Users\MyUsername\SharePointSite.....'

However, if I call it from VBA, the script's working directory is 'C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents' and it fails to find the batch.

If I do a ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path before calling the batch it works, however ChDir does not seem to fix the issue with calling the PS script. I can use the batch file for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:

```
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
Call Shell(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TryShell.bat " & ThisWorkbook.Path)
```

TryShell.bat

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& './FTP/FTP.ps1'"
```